# Compass not finishing with gulp

Tags: gulp, compass

When I run gulp, the 'styles' task starts running and sits forever, never finishing and not throwing any error. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall everything I can think of, and nothing seems to make a difference.

This is the function that is not finishing:

```
gulp.task('styles', function buildStyles() {
  return gulp
    .src(stylesGulpPaths)
    // Copy scss files to build/scss for compass.
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scss'))
    // But only compile main.scss, which imports the rest.
    .pipe(filter('**/main.scss'))
    .pipe(compass({
      css: 'build/css',
      http_path: '/',
      // image: 'build/images',
      require: ['compass/import-once/activate', 'sass-globbing'],
      sass: 'build/scss',
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) { console.error(err.message); })
    // 'Concatenate' our one file so we write it to
    // build/css/main.css
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulpif(args.production, minifycss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});


var stylesGulpPaths = [
  'app/**/*.scss',
  '!app/vendor/**/*.scss',
];
```

Version:

```
gulp -v => 3.9.1

compass -v => 1.1.0.alpha.3 (Polaris)

node -v => 5.6.0
```

In my console it gets to the Starting 'styles'... line and just stays there forever.

I am pointing the correct ruby version (2.1.2).

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

There were conflicting compass versions. I just had to uninstall compass, compass-rails, and sass-rails and reinstall compass.